# Root Domain 301 Redirect Except Checkout Page - 2 Sites Merged

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, ecommerce

I have a client who is merging his two ecommerce websites into one. The first ecommerce site is about knowledge of the products and second ecommerce website is to buy the product. It is interlinked with each other.

Now, he decided to merge it into one whole website and redirecting everything from second website to this first one except CHECKOUT page. That means, you'll add to cart the product from the first website but the checkout will be done from second website.

So, my query is - when you are redirecting 301 the whole website from root domain to each and every page, how can you keep checkout page static? won't that be also redirected?

So, i'm asking here - Is it possible to redirect every page except checkout page?

Please let me know the answer, so I'll share this with my developers.

Thanks.